# Adding OCMock to a framework

Tags: frameworks, linker-errors, ocunit, ocmock

A bit of background first, I am currently writing some ocunit tests for a universal framework, and now need to add OCMock to test some networking aspects of the framework. I have followed the OCMock instructions [here](http://ocmock.org/) and downloaded the sample project as a reference. I've added libOCMock.a in Link Binary with Libraries in the Build phases and added the header location to Header Search path and set the linker flags to

```
-ObjC
-force_load
"$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/libOCMock.a"
```

- The error message I'm getting when I run my tests is as follows:

`ld: 73 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Turns out - I just had to delete and re-add libOCMock.a -- very odd -- and yet another day wasted!

Comment: Do you have a version of the broken project file in source control? It would be interesting to see what went wrong the first time round. It's such a shame that we still have to resort to using libraries on iOS. I wish Apple would let us use frameworks.

Comment: No, what is really strange is that I actually removed and readded exactly the same file (have it stored elsewhere locally) - The problems I've had wit OCMock is really putting me off testing my code. In another project I added OCMock with the same process as above and got the same error, the only way I could resolve it is by either removing libOCMock.a from either Link Binary with Libraries or the reference to the file in the xcode project.

Comment: Well, you won't see me defending Apple's build system. I've had my fair share of issues with it, too. I don't believe there's anything that's specific to OCMock, or fixable by OCMock, in this regard. Or is there?